# Как кэшировать JS и CSS файлы, а также изображения?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, pagespeed-insights

**Добавлено**

Скорее всего дело в настройках конфигурации Nginx.

**Оригинал**

Гугл указал мне на мои ошибки:

> Используйте кеш браузера
>
> Если указывать в заголовках HTTP дату или
>   срок действия статических ресурсов, браузер будет загружать уже
>   полученные ранее ресурсы с локального диска, а не из Интернета.

Ну и ниже список. Приведу его часть:

```
https://mc.yandex.ru/metrika/watch.js (60 минут)
https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js (2 часа)
http://site.com/…15877ddfa223e8a8a7533474f07.woff?v=4.7.0 (4 часа)
http://site.com/…98cf4de8c1914ef7e8afc9a9abefe3693e57.jpg (4 часа)
http://site.com/…62479c3d86a76ab7143d4dc639a6f5f67daa.jpg (4 часа)

# Далее также перечислены .js и .css файлы с такой же структурой,
# как и .jpg файлы выше в списке.
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но я вообще думал, что наличие хэша в имени файла это как раз для кэша браузера. В старых версиях Rails использовался такой вид, да:

```
/stylesheets/global.css?1309495796
```

Но в новых версиях используется хэш:

```
global-908e25f4bf641868d8683022a5b62f54.css
```

Ну так написано в [официальной документации](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html).

Так что это такое? В чем косяк мой?

Comment: Вы удивитесь, но Ruby on Rails тут вообще ни при чём. Вам надо настроить вебсервер, который раздаёт ассеты. Опишите подробности в этом направлении.

Comment: @D-side можете намекнуть на настройку (имя) в Nginx конфиге (если я правильно понял о чем речь)? Потому что я что-то делал там по этой теме, опираясь на мануалы с сайта DO.

Comment: Во-от, то есть, уже нужна метка `nginx` и конфиг в вопросе. А настройка называется, кажется, `expires`.

Comment: Где-то же указано 4 часа. Надо найти и заменить на год (или 10 лет)